# Stripe Payment Confirmation - PHP

Tags: stripe-payments

Hope some PHP gurus can help me out with this. I am creating a simple donation form to accept payments using Stripe. I have included my code here. The form works fine in terms of processing payments. However, the script is supposed to send a confirmation email to the donor, saying that their donation has been received, etc. The issue I am having is that the script does not send such a confirmation. I am using GoDaddy hosting and have checked that my MX records are correct. I ran test from my hosting account (with help of GoDaddy support) as well to see if there's any issue with the account itself. The tests showed no such issues. I have tried minor tweaks such as changing headers, adding <>, etc., but no luck.

Here's my code for config.php

```
<?php
 return array(
'test-mode'       => true,
'secret-key'      => 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY',
'publishable-key' => 'YOUR_PUBLISHABLE_KEY',
'thank-you'       => 'http://example.com/thank-you.html',
'email-from'      => 'no-reply@example.com',
'email-bcc'       => 'admin@example.com',
'email-subject'   => 'Thank you for your donation!',
'email-message'   => "Dear %name%,\n\nThank you for your order of %amount%."
);
```

Here's my code for index.php

```
<?php
require('lib/Stripe.php');
$config = require('config.php');
if ($config['test-mode'] && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on') {
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] .   $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
exit;
}
  if ($_POST) {
  Stripe::setApiKey($config['secret-key']);

$token      = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$first_name = $_POST['first-name'];
$last_name  = $_POST['last-name'];
$name       = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;
$address    = $_POST['address'] . "\n" . $_POST['city'] . ', ' . $_POST['state'] . ' ' . $_POST['zip'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$phone      = $_POST['phone'];
$amount     = (float) $_POST['amount'];
try {
    if ( ! isset($_POST['stripeToken']) ) {
        throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");
    }

    // Charge the card
    $donation = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
        'card'        => $token,
        'description' => 'Donation by ' . $name . ' (' . $email . ')',
        'amount'      => $amount * 100,
        'currency'    => 'usd'
    ));

    // Build and send the email
    $headers = 'From: ' . $config['emaily-from'];
    $headers .= "\r\nBcc: " . $config['emaily-bcc'] . "\r\n\r\n";

    // Find and replace values
    $find    = array('%name%', '%amount%');
    $replace = array($name, '$' . $amount);

    $message = str_replace($find, $replace , $config['email-message']) . "\n\n";
    $message .= 'Amount: $' . $amount . "\n";
    $message .= 'Address: ' . $address . "\n";
    $message .= 'Phone: ' . $phone . "\n";
    $message .= 'Email: ' . $email . "\n";
    $message .= 'Date: ' . date('M j, Y, g:ia', $donation['created']) . "\n";
    $message .= 'Transaction ID: ' . $donation['id'] . "\n\n\n";

    $subject = $config['email-subject'];

    // Send it
    if ( !$config['test-mode'] ) {
        mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }

    // Forward to "Thank You" page
    header('Location: ' . $config['thank-you']);
    exit;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Stripe Payment Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('<?php echo $config['publishable-key'] ?>');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Stripe Payment Form</h1>
    <p><strong>Thanks for donating!</strong></p>
    <div class="messages">
        <!-- Error messages go here go here -->
    </div>

    <form action="#" method="POST" class="donation-form">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Contact Information
            </legend>
            <div class="form-row form-first-name">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first-name" class="first-name text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row form-last-name">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="last-name" class="last-name text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row form-email">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="email text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row form-phone">
                <label>Phone</label>
                <input type="text" name="phone" class="phone text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row form-address">
                <label>Address</label>
                <textarea name="address" cols="30" rows="2" class="address text"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row form-city">
                <label>City</label>
                <input type="text" name="city" class="city text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row form-state">
                <label>State</label>
                <select name="state" class="state text">
                    <option value="AL">AL</option>
                    <option value="WY">WY</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row form-zip">
                <label>Zip</label>
                <input type="text" name="zip" class="zip text">
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Your Generous Donation
            </legend>
            <div class="form-row form-amount">
                <label><input type="radio" name="amount" class="set-  amount" value="25"> $25</label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="amount" class="set-amount" value="100"> $100</label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="amount" class="other-amount" value="0"> Other:</label> <input type="text" class="amount text" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row form-number">
                <label>Card Number</label>
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="card-number text" value="4242424242424242">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row form-cvc">
                <label>CVC</label>
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="card-cvc text" value="123">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row form-expiry">
                <label>Expiration Date</label>
                <select class="card-expiry-month text">
                    <option value="01" selected>January</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
                </select>
                <select class="card-expiry-year text">
                    <option value="2017" selected>2017</option>
                    <option value="2018">2018</option>
                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row form-submit">
                <input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Submit Donation">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<script>if (window.Stripe) $('.donation-form').show()</script>
<noscript><p>JavaScript is required for the donation form.</p></noscript>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything in your `error.log`? If you enable verbose error reporting do you get any warnings or errors? `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, no error log is generated. Also, no warnings as well.